# How to use two Qt5 versions on KDE Plasma to avoid conflict?

Tags: linux, qt, kde-plasma

I am using Opensuse Leap 42.3, with KDE Plasma 5.8.7 which uses **Qt 5.6.2**.
I would like to use the latest Qt version (**5.10** as of asking this question) for development, and I've installed it in `/usr/local/Qt5.10/`.
I added Qt5.10 library path (`/usr/local/Qt5.10/5.10.0/gcc_64/lib/`) to my `/etc/ld.so.conf` but it caused a conflict with system's Qt version, which as a result anything using Qt libs (Dolphin, Kate, etc) won't work, and if logged out, cannot login, complaining about qdbus.
I tried to create symlinks in /usr/lib64 like this:

```
for f in /usr/local/Qt5.10/5.10.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5*.so.5.10; do
ln -s $f /usr/lib;
done
```

But this too, made the same problem. I have also added a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` entry in ~/.profile but with the same problem.
I can do `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/Qt5.10/5.10.0/gcc_64/lib/"` in a terminal and run my Qt5.10 application, but this is not convenient.
What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It may not be convenient, but setting the path up as you launch seems to be the only way to avoid the issues you mention.

I also use KDE, and am playing with Qt 5.10 visualisation stuff on a system using Qt 5.9 and have experienced the hell of mashed library dependencies you mention.

Qt Creator seems to take care of that and in other environments (eg: KDevelop) you can add it to the path in the run/debug launch settings.  And although not portable, you could also add it to the path for your desktop file...

The qtchooser utility might be useful although I admit I don't really understand how it's supposed to work.
Yes, I realise this is a low quality answer but I am interested in seeing a better solution too.